# angularjs : Pushing object into Array

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to display user details by searching with their id. Everytime I search the table gets refreshed and the $scope.userdetails is not being appended with the new value. I want the old value to stay and on clicking the search button a new row should get appended. Below is the code i use.

Below is the angular code:

```
result = $http.get('/*API comes here */', {
      params: t
   })
   .then(function(response) {
      //angular.merge($scope.userdetails, response.data);
      result = response.data;
      $scope.userdetails.push(result);
      //angular.forEach(result, function (value, key) {
      //    $scope.userdetails.push(value);
      //})

      //$scope.userdetails.concat(result);

      console.log(result);
      console.log($scope.userdetails);
      //console.log(result);
   }, function(response) {
      alert('Failed ' + JSON.stringify(response.statusText));
   });
```

HTML code:

```
<form>
   <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
         <select class="dropdown form-control" data-size="5" id="Userlookup" ng-model="search.ddlUserlookup">
                                    <option value="1">Email ID</option>
                                    <option value="2">WW ID</option>
                                </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Userlookup" ng-model="search.txtUserlookup">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="fetchDetails()">Search</button>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div>
      <table class="table table-bordered">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th class="col-sm-4">Full Name</th>
               <th class="col-sm-6">Email ID</th>
               <th class="col-sm-3">WW ID</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="ud in userdetails">
               <td>{{ud.FirstName +' '+ ud.LastName}}</td>
               <td>{{ud.EmailID}}</td>
               <td>{{ud.WWID}}</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Do the two console.log()'s that you have, show anything?

Comment: Nothing shown would cause that behavior. Problem is elsewhere in code we can't see

Comment: the output of result log is Object->0:object->required data

Comment: for $scope.userdetails log, [Array(1)]->0:Array(1)->0:object